# React useEffect hook event listener fired twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
        }, [props.tps])
```

For some reason, though, on the associated key press, the handleKeyPress function is called twice. I tried adding handleKeyPress as a dependency and that does not work, either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I saw this late but for others who may have this problem:
it is probably because of `React.StrictMode` inside `index.js` and it is an intentional thing when using hooks.
here is the [reference](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you added `props.tps`, but try to remove it from dependency arrays.

Comment: I look for a change in props.tps for the effect to fire.

Comment: It isn't a good approach to add event listener every time the props.tps is changed. Do you have any other code lines inside the callback? If not, you can absolutely remove it from deps array.

Comment: it is not an issue as there's a unregistering call.

Answer (score 0):

`props.tps` is not doing anything there, you need to delete the `props.tps` from the dependency array because:

1.- The event listener (as it's not from the component itself but from `window`) should be created on the "componentDidMount" or what's equivalent an empty dependency array.

2.- The values on the dependency array should be also inside the useEffect function to make it work properly.

Try taking it out the dependency array.

Comment: Put a console.log inside the useEffect() to see how many times is firing...

1.- Maybe you have a second instance of that component that's making the same eventListener.

2.- Try putting a const to name that event and clear that name, to avoid having 2 instance of the event.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `reactStrictMode` config, if it's `true` change it to `false`.

In my case I use `NextJs` and it's located in `next.config.js`.

`reactStrictMode` only affect development only and not in production.